# Apexcharts Heatmap remove tooltip on x-axis

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

trying to set up Heatmap with a label every 5 columns on axis-x and 100 on axis-y. I do it this way:

```
     xaxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function(value) {
                if (value % 5 === 0) {
                    return value;
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

And see a weird "tooltip" on x-axis that misses a value.

[image]

Do you know how to get rid of this? Or maybe better, do you know a better way of skipping values on x-axis and still keep this "tooltip" functional?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you provide full code for Heatmap chart?

Comment: I'm not a JavaScript, so the code looks accordingly :D 
https://github.com/petrbouda/jeffrey/blob/master/pages/src/views/flamegraph/OtherHeatmaps.vue
https://github.com/petrbouda/jeffrey/blob/master/pages/src/service/HeatmapGraphApex.js

Comment: Thanks, I cloned the jeffrey project. And cd pages, 'npm install', 'npm run dev" and open "http://localhost:5173/" by browser but UI did not display Hitmap even if drop 'heatmap-apex.data'. How to display your Hitmap?